# Can't load a file to mysql table: Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I want to load file into a table. I am using this command.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'home/myuser/Documents/my_project/project_sub_directory/project_sub_directory2/project_sub_directory3/my_data_file.txt'
INTO TABLE `mydatabse`.`my_table`
fields terminated BY ',';
```

I use `LOCAL` in the command to avoid the following error (an avoid moving my data files to another directory):

> Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the
>   --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

After executing the command, I get this error:

> Error Code: 2. File
>   'home/myuser/Documents/my_project/project_sub_directory/project_sub_directory2/project_sub_directory3/my_data_file.txt'
>   not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

How to resolve the issue without moving my data file to another directory?